# header and body setting in get method in angular 4

Tags: angular, httpclient

I want to set "API Key" and "Accept" in HTTP header. I would also like to add auth-token, page-no, page-size in the body. Can anybody help me?

Below is the code snippet I tried so far :

```
const body = {
            auth_token: '',
            type: 'matrix',
            page_no: '1',
            page_size: '20',
            keyword: 'j',
        };
        const header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.append('X-API-KEY', '');
        header.append('Accept', 'application/json');
         return this.http.get('', { headers: header} **body**)
            .map
            (
                (reponse: Response) => {
                    const resp = reponse.json();
                    return resp;
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Please put your code inside code block so users can read easily.

Comment: done i also want to send body with headers

Answer (score 1):

Instance of HttpHeaders is immutable, you have to do:

`let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('X-API-KEY', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
const header=new HttpHeader({
   'X-API-KEY': '',
   'Accept': 'application/json'
})
```